# Open SaveAs dialog for ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I'm using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer and I want to catch the download event, right now the library support `(pdfDownloaded)` but this fires when a user click on download icon and it downloads the pdf straight away instead I need it to open the Save As dialog. How can I achieve this?

Library APIs: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/attributes

Comment: its something we set at the chrome level configuration! [article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-save-as-prompt-in-google-chrome)